# Integrals with erf^N

Tags: probability-theory, special-functions, normal-distribution

Can anyone help with integral of type. In general, what to do if erf is in power higher than 1?

$$g(S|S<L)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^L \exp \left ( \frac{-(x-z)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right )  dx \right ]^3 \exp \left ( \frac{-(z-S)^2}{2 \sigma^2} \right ) dz$$

[Better looking formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVhgD.jpg)

Comment: Sure that `erf(-(x-z)^2/(2σ^2 ))` is involved, not simply `erf(z)`?

Comment: OK, the formula in the post and in the link are different...

Comment: I've removed the formula you wrote and replaced it with the formula from the link, since the two were not consistent with one another.

Comment: Anyway, this almost certainly has no closed form solution. You might have a shot at finding one if you changed variables so that $u^2=(x-z)^2/2\sigma^2$ and $v^2=(z-S)^2/2\sigma^2$.

Comment: I agree with Ian. One very special case where the exact value can be found is $S = L$, where the answer is $1/4$.